# ReactJS content not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This part belong to something like blog, react get data from api:

**Page.js:**

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let alias = this.props.match.params.name;
    const result = await API.getPage(alias);
    if(result.status === 200){
        document.title = 'Page - ' + result.data.title;
        this.setState({
            title: result.data.title,
            body: result.data.body
        })
    }
}
```

And this is router:

```
<Route exact path='/Page/:name' component={Page}></Route>
```

For example, when you open website (homepage) and click this link in footer:

```
<li><Link to="/Page/HowItWorks">How It Works</Link></li>
```

It work and open this content, but when I am in this page `/Page/..` and click on another footer link, it won't update, just url change, but if I refresh page, it get correct content.

What I have missed?

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` for when the match prop changes.

Comment: @DrewReese But I see, when I refresh page, it not working anymore :(

Comment: When you reload page everything is loaded from scratch, i.e. the components remount. Can you be more specific as to what isn't working anymore?

Comment: First, you mean I just use componentDidUpdate instead of componentDidMount right? okay, I did, but when I reload page, page is blank, react won't request data from API, nothing in network tab @DrewReese

Comment: @tourtravel `componentDidMount` only runs once on component mounting, `componentDidUpdate` runs whenever your state or props change.

So you would have to use both the lifecycles.

One for mounting and other for subsequent updates.

Comment: @UtsavPatel It seems using both lifecycles solve this issue, but it give me a creepy issue, after content load, it doing request again to api every single second, after 30 seconds, it stop and give error `429 Too Many Requests` why? any idea? I don't want to update every seconds!

Comment: @tourtravel you need to place a check, basically to check that if nothing has changed then do nothing.

Currently this is happening --> state change --> didupdate called --> state change --> didupdate called.
So just place a check using `prevProps`,`prevState` & `this.state`, `this.props`

Comment: Yes, sorry, also using `componentDidUpdate`, in addition to `componentDidMount`, to do the initial fetch when the component mounts ***and*** also to refetch whenever `match` prop updates. You can't just blindly setState in `componentDidUpdate` though as that'll cause an infinite loop since `componentDidUpdate` is triggered by *both* state **and** prop updates. You only want to refetch when `match` updates, not when any other state/prop value updates.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Sorry I didn't get it, can you provide an answer?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry I didn't get it, can you provide an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can factor your asynchronous code into a utility function that can be called by either lifecycle function. In `componentDidMount` you can just freely call it. In `componentDidUpdate` you should compare the `match` value from the previous render cycle to the value from the current cycle.

```
async fetchPage() {
  const alias = this.props.match.params.name;
  const result = await API.getPage(alias);
  if (result.ok) {
    document.title = 'Page - ' + result.data.title;
    this.setState({
      title: result.data.title,
      body: result.data.body
    })
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetchPage();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { name } = this.props.match;
  const { name: prevName} = prevProps.match;

  if (prevName !== name) {
    fetchPage();
  }
}
```